# Weird thing happens when i apply transforms to mesh (photo)

Tags: bezier-curves, transforms

Helo, i used curves to create hair. I converted it to mesh. But i cant aplly all transforms. When i do aplly all transforms my mesh gets destroyed and looks weird.

The same problem appears when i try to merge it with other mesh :( it weirdly changes shape.

Does anyone know what could be wrong ?[image]

Comment: Just apply scale & rotation - does this work for you?

Comment: Are you using a mapping node for your shader?

Comment: @Chris , so i tried only scale&rotation, the problem was similar. And i tried to test wich transform was wrong. I applyed separately rotation, separately location etc. It turns out its something connected to - Scale - only apply scale destroys mesh (so combo aply scale & rotation does the same)

Comment: @brockmann , no i dont use mapping node. I have uv ready and painted.

Comment: Ok, then please provide your blend file

Answer (score 1):

I foud out how to fix the mesh! [I just had to fix normals: normals/recalculate outside, and that fixed the mesh :) i dont know why they got broken in the first place though XD. Thanks everyone who comented to help me!

[image]